# Why can't I host my manifest.xml on a webserver?

Tags: office-js

I've got a small client (2 users) that have hired me to build a Word add-in. There's no centralised deployment or any substantial infrastructure; it's the two of them and their laptops.

About the only way that I can think of is to side-load with a local network share per machine. But if/when that messes up, it's another support issue I don't really want to deal with; not to mention more setup when they hire more people.

This limitation is confusing to me. It's just reading the manifest.xml, it shouldn't matter if it's from a network share or an HTTPS request.

Comment: Is there no 3rd machine that could have the network share folder?

Answer (score 1):

That is not possible today. I think your best bet is to establish a shared folder, but this add-in will not work in the Web Clients or Mac. Another option is to use a sharepoint based catalog if the customer has access to it.  Given that this is only 2 users you can also have a local shared folder.