# Hosting Office Add-in Manifest.xml File in Cloud Storage Platforms like Google Drive

Tags: excel, manifest, office-addins, cloud-storage, excel-web-addins

Is it possible to host the Office Add-in **Manifest.xml** file in cloud storage platforms such as Google Drive or OneDrive?

Even though I have shared the Manifest.xml files in Google Drive storage and manually added the shared URL to the Excel Trusted Add-in Catalogs, the add-ins do not display and it seems not working.

Comment: What does developer tools (F12) says when you try to navigate to the file in the browser? Is the file publicly available?

Comment: thanks for your comment, actually after adding it to the trusted add-in catalog and restart excel, nothing appear in excel addin tabs thus nothing to load, same manifest works if i but the it in share network . the file publicly accessible as well

Comment: Have you tried using developer tools (F12) in your web browser or Fiddler for looking any possible errors when requesting the manifest file?

Comment: Hello, after extensive search, i think it is not supported to do this but couldn't find any offical document mention this. Thanks for your time!
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65858449/why-cant-i-host-my-manifest-xml-on-a-webserver?rq=4